# Any use other than selling for items whose 'Recommended Use' is 'Sell"?

Tags: far-cry-3

In Far Cry 3, when looking at items in your loot rucksack, each item has a 'Recommended Use.'  Some say to craft certain things with them, but others simply say 'Sell.'  I was wondering if there is any reason (needed for a quest/achievement/trophy/crafting later) to hold on to any of the items that they recommend to sell or if I might as well sell them all.  I'd hate to take up room in my rucksack for things that I should just sell anyway, but I'd also hate to sell my Batteries just to find a quest to bring someone 10 batteries later.

Comment: Insert broom dungeon reference here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've played the game and looked through the wiki, there is no use that I've seen for the miscellaneous items that you gather from loot chests and dead bodies. The names for everything is just filler, make the player feel a sense of pride when he picks up a Diamond or Smartphone. The only quest items you will gather would be herbs and leather, occasionally some other item that you can only get while performing the quest.