# How can I skip skinning/looting animations in Far Cry 3?

Tags: far-cry-3

Aside from dancing around dead bodies in an attempt to find the proper pointing spot for "Press <kbd>E</kbd> to skin", my most frustrating issue with Far Cry 3 is the amount of time it takes for the looting or skinning animation to play whenever I take these actions.

It seems like the game skips these animations in some cases (I've seen it 2 or 3 times) but no alternate application of the <kbd>E</kbd> key during skinning/looting changes the animation duration. Have I stumbled upon a bug with the animation skipping or is there something I can do to skip the animation myself?

Comment: I too have seen the case where the animation doesn't play. I think it's simply a case where your character isn't physically in the right spot for the animation to play (i.e. the animation would cause your character to clip into a neighboring object). That said, a way to skip those animations would be awesome.

Comment: Anyone know if skipping skinning/looting animations can be modded into the game?

Comment: you just need to replace the animation file with one that's faster
just google for invalidanim.mab for full instructions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to stop the animations unless the body is ragdolled in such a way that the animation is prevented from happening.

The only way is to opt for the Loot Takedown skill, which will automatically loot enemies on a takedown. But after the bullets start flying, takedowns aren't easily executed.