# Is there a trick to skinning and looting?

Tags: far-cry-3

Is there a trick to this? I just spent a good 30 seconds trying to pickup a relic despite tea-bagging the stupid thing.

I've had similar trouble with skinning animals; finding that I have to be in a specific spot for it to work at all.

Don't even get me started on the number of times I've thrown my super awesome weapon when trying to loot an enemy!

Is there a trick to this, or a place or stand or what? It can't surely be a matter of running around tea-bagging corpses for 5 minutes after every battle!

Comment: I don't know if this will help or just add to your frustration, but in the general case looting corpses or skinning animals is flat out not worth it. If you're not crafting and you're not looting the target of an assassination mission, you're going to wind up cluttering your inventory with sub-$100 kipple. In fact, I eventually regretted taking the "loot on takedown" perk, because I never have room for harvested plants when I need them.

Comment: Related: [How can I skip skinning/looting animations in Far Cry 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102257/4797)

Comment: @Tacroy Good shout, and I just took that skill too!

Comment: @galacticninja I'm not sure how these are related except that they are about skinning and looting, but I hoped that they would be seen as different questions. Could you suggest an edit?

Comment: @DavidYell I'm not saying that this question is a duplicate of that one. I'm saying that they're related (but different) questions, because they both talk about making skinning and looting easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an annoying part of the game.  The only real 'trick' is to make sure you stand directly over the point where the animal is glowing, and you see the prompt on the screen to skin.

Same thing goes for the looting.  Though, this is a much more annoying issue.  The person drops the gun right next to him.  You need to make sure that the game is NOT prompting you to pick up a gun, but to Loot the Body.  The two points are so close, that you can jiggle between the two.

It takes practice, but I have gotten very good at this.

Comment: Sounds legit. I was really hoping there was a better way than just having to hover about loads. Oh well, I might take @Tacroy advice and just not bother looting.

Answer (score 0):

On Xbox I hold X as I walk up to the object, which skins/loots/whatever it as soon as I hit the sweet spot.  I found this a bit quicker and easier than pressing X when the prompt appears.