# Is there a point to collecting as many cyber-hearts as possible?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

In Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon, cyber-hearts are looted from fallen enemies. Similar to Far Cry 3, [looting / pilfering takes some time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102257/4797), which can be quite annoying when you have or want to do it frequently.

I learned that cyber-hearts can be used to lure blood dragons to a location. Aside from that, **are there other uses for the cyber-hearts?**

**Should I attempt to collect as many cyber-hearts as possible or just stockpile enough to be able to lure blood dragons?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can only hold 99 hearts, and when you get the skill for auto-loot on takedown, this number will be reached very quickly (if you do a lot of takedowns of course). You'll probably only use maybe 25 hearts throughout the whole game, though. I would still continue to loot cyber soldiers (just not obsessively), because they do give money.

Answer (score 4):

Cyberhearts are only useful for luring blood-dragons. You rarely need to do that, and when you do, you only need a few of them.

But notice that looting enemies does not just give you cyber hearts, it also gives you some credits.