# Heavy Beatdown takedown skill unlocked, but unable to use

Tags: far-cry-3

I have already unlocked the Heavy Beatdown skill in 'The Shark' skill tree. The lock is removed but it is unusable and has no effect when I double click it. I have 1500 xp out of 4000.

What should I do to use the Heavy Beatdown skill in 'The Shark' skill tree?

Comment: Are you sure you've unlocked the skills adjacent to it? Sometime before you you can unlock a skill, you need to unlock a previous one

Comment: Can you provide a picture / screenshot ?

Answer (score 3):

You must unlock the skill adjacent to it (Grenade Takedown, which requires 5 kills with grenades) *and* kill one [Bull Shark](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Bull_Shark) (Heavy Beatdown skill requirement), before you can get the Heavy Beatdown skill.

Tips for killing bull sharks include [running them over with a boat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/98002/4797) or [use a boat with a mounted machine gun and blast them with it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95854/how-do-i-make-a-lot-of-money-efficiently/96254#comment137501_98002).