# How do I make a lot of money / dollars efficiently?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

I'm currently at an early of the game. I would like to have as much money as possible to be able to buy as many weapon attachments as possible, which I'm currently trying to collect.

**What are efficient ways to get the big bucks (maximum money for minimum effort, preferably methods which are repeatable) in Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon?** Money-saving tips or strategies would be useful, too.

Also, will money still be an issue at the later parts of the game? (I'm asking because [in Far Cry 3, it isn't](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95854/4797)).

---

Related: [(Far Cry 3)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95854/4797) [How do I make a lot of money efficiently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95854/4797)

Comment: I’ve found by end game I had purchased everything with quite a bit of money left over. I think I remember it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Your sources of money are (in order of amount):

- Looting chests
- Doing side-missions
- Collecting collectibles
- Picking up money laying around
- Looting dead cyber-soldiers
- Looting dead animals

Your best way to make money is by exploring any buildings, ruins, caves and other points of interest you see on your map. Most of these have at least one collectible and/or chest and some lootable money piles. While you do so, you often get opportunities to take out some cyber-soldiers which also reward you with some cash when ripping out their hearts. Animals also give some money, but it's a lot less than soldiers, so hunting animals isn't really a viable source of income.

Comment: +1 for some great points. When attempting to complete the achievement of collecting all the TV sets, you will come across many chests that contain $300+, so whenever you need money, just start going after the TV sets. Also, I would suggest beating the game first to get the Arm Laser shooting weapon (sorry I can't remember the name). This weapon makes killing things much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Money is pretty difficult throughout the game (except the very beginning), especially when some upgrades cost 3k+. I was able to get everything unlocked just by finding supply crates, each one has anywhere from 200-400$ inside. There is always at least one in any Point of Interest.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, here are some money saving tips I found so far:

- The 'Refill Inventory' option when buying in a shop refills the ammo for all equipped weapons, throwables, and explosives for a 20% discount. Buy those items through this option whenever possible.
- The [Terror 4000](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Terror_4000) eats up a lot of ammo, and its ammo is expensive. Try to use other weapons whenever possible, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing out garrisons and searching the ruins for treasure is a good start.

Also performing chained takedowns and pilfering enemies is a good little money earner.

Even on hard you do not need to purchase all of the weapon attachments to win the game.

Later in the game you can take down blood dragons for cash but you will struggle 
to afford all of the weapon upgrades in the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill dragons and that can give you 100 - 300 a dragon. Use a car with a machine gun to kill them. It doesnt take long to kill alot. Alternatively some garrisons have machine guns and you can use those, just shut off the shields and bait the dragon in and then just kill it.